# Проверить AntiForgeryToken в ajax-запросе?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Изучаю особенности asp.net core 2.0 на небольших приложениях. Хочу например сделать небольшой ajax-запрос к списку контактов.

Вот есть у меня моделька

```
public class ContactSearchViewModel
{
    public string Needle { get; set; }
}
```

и формочка:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Search" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Needle"></label>
                <input asp-for="Needle" class="form-control" onchange="getSummary(this.value);" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</div>

function getSummary(needle) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Contact/Search/',
        data: "Needle=" + needle,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

И всё прекрасно работает... есть только одна маленькая досада: мне пришлось закомментировать ValidateAntiForgeryToken:

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search(ContactSearchViewModel model)
    {
        var contacts = await this.ContactService.SearchAsync(model.Needle);
        return View(contacts);
    }
```

Если строку раскомментировать - то запросы до action не доходят (брейкпойнт не срабатывает), заворачиваются с 400 Bad Request где-то раньше в недрах вебсервера.

Вопрос простой: как правильно создавать ajax-запросы в .core чтобы они проходили валидацию?

Comment: Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript-ajax-and-spas) нужен токен в заголовке звпроса

Comment: @Kazantsev Точно, теперь работает! Дооформите ответом до галки?

Comment: Да, сейчас постараюсь оформить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript-ajax-and-spas) в представлении нужно добавить метод получения токена и скрытое поле:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions {
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}

<input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken" 
   name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">
```

и добавить в запрос заголовок с полученным токеном:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    headers:
    {
        "RequestVerificationToken": $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
    },
    ...
});
```