# Как из Angularjs передать данные в Asp net core через POST ajax

Tags: c#, angularjs, post, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь передать данные в контроллер, приходит null. (PUT работает нормально)

View:

```
var app = angular.module('onns', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('ONNController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = null;
    $scope.expressionForm = null;
    $scope.info = null;
    $scope.putdata = function () {                        
        var params = {
            name: $scope.nameNew,
            expressionForm: tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(),                
            info: $scope.infoNew
        };            
        $http({
            url: '/ONN/AddMainNameONN',
            method: 'POST',
            data: params                
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.res) {
                $scope.msg = "Put Data Method Executed Successfully!";
                var idNewMainNameONN = response.data.res;
                console.log(params);  
            }
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.msg = "Service not Exists";
            $scope.statusval = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
            $scope.headers = response.headers();               

        });
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult AddMainNameONN(string name, string expressionForm, string info)
    {          
            var item = mng.MainNameONN.AddMainNameONN(name, expressionForm, info);

            var res = new
            {
                res = item.id,
            };
            return Json(res);

    }
```

Что сделал не так?

Comment: Не уверен, но подозреваю, что вы столкнулись с проблемой AntiForgeryToken.  [Почитайте этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803903/213987), в нём есть ссылки на документацию майкрософт и примеры. Потом адаптируйте к своему коду.

Comment: В POST запросе параметры передаются в теле запроса. Пометьте параметры контроллера тегом [FromBody]. И тут еще посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574149/198316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример POST метода контроллера

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Auth([FromBody] TokenRequest tokenRequest)
    {
        //.......
    }
```

Обратите внимание на явно указанный тип запроса `[HttpPost]` и явное указание, откуда брать модель `[FromBody]`.