# Как передать сложный объект в Post-запросе С#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Изучаю Asp.Net web api. Делаю контроллер:

```
// POST: api/Users  
    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.Id }, user);
    }
```

*(Вернее, по факту этот контроллер сделала визуальная студия)*
Почитал про привязку модели, но почти ничего не понял.
Вот так я пытаюсь отправлять POST-запрос:

```
    public void PostUser(User user)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($"http://localhost:{port}/api/Users");

        request.Method = "POST";
        using (System.IO.Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            var jsonUserSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(User));
            jsonUserSerializer.WriteObject(stream, user);
        }
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    }
```

Однако во всех случаях получаю
`System.Net.WebException: "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (415) Unsupported Media Type."`
Установка заголовка ContentType в "application/json" тоже не помогла.
Возможно важный момент: у меня используются разные классы User.

```
// User из сборки с Web api
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
// User из сборки с клиентом, отправляющим запрос
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из Angularjs передать данные в Asp net core через POST ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858402/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-angularjs-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-asp-net-core-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-post-ajax)

Comment: Сталкивался с таким, надо не только Content-Type, но и Accept в заголовке передать.